# How to get radio and checkbox value in using Modal Bootstrap PHP Mysql

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to add `.val(tag)` for checbox and `.val(bahasa)` for radio for displaying values of it in a Modal bootsrap. But it won't display any values of the selected radio nor checkbox in the Modal popup:( Does anyone know how to do the `.val` correctly for both radio and checkbox?

Here's my code:

```
      <script>
            $(document).on("click", "#tombolUbah", function() {
                let id = $(this).data('id');
                let judul = $(this).data('judul');
                let penulis = $(this).data('penulis');
                let tahun = $(this).data('tahun');
                let deskripsi = $(this).data('deskripsi');
                let gambar = $(this).data('gambar');
                let tag = $(this).data('tag');
                let bahasa = $(this).data('bahasa');

                $("#id_buku").val(id);
                    $("#judul_buku").val(judul);
                    $("#penulis_buku").val(penulis);
                    $("#tahun_terbit").val(tahun);
                    $("#deskripsi").val(deskripsi);
                    $("#gambar").val(gambar);
                    $("#tag").val(tag);
                    $("#bahasa").val(bahasa);
            })
        </script>
```

Thank you so much :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP or mysql. Re-tag it with HTML and jQuery and show the related HTML so that we've got a [mre] of the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Comment: For radio buttons. `element.attr('checked', true);`

Answer (score 0):

Getting values from the **checkbox**:

```
$( "input[type=checkbox][name=tag]:checked" ).val();
```

Getting values from the **RadioBox**:

```
$( "input[type=radio][name=bahasa]:checked" ).val();
```

[reference](http://www.tutorialspanel.com/checkboxes-radio-buttons-jquery/index.htm)